# Equality of spans proof

Tags: linear-algebra

In V=C(R), let $S_{1} = \{sin(x), cos(x), sin^{2}(x), cos^{2}(x)\}$ and $S_{2} = \{1, sin(2x), cos(2x)\}$. Is $Span(S_{1}) = Span(S_{2})$? Why or why not?

What I have done to solve this problem is: I know that somehow the double angle formula comes to play here. I also know (before someone answered then deleted their comment) that to show that two things are equal $x \subset v$ and $v \subset x$. I just don't see the answer clearly because I am completely new to linear algebra and i'm just a student trying to learn and trying to understand some basic concepts which might be regarded as baby stuff to expert professionals such as yourselves :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\sin x$ is in the span of $S_1$, which has period $2 \pi$, are there any functions in the span of $S_2$ with this period?